# incremental encoder with added joystick functionality

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-control, arduino, home-electronics

I was searching the web for days now and just couldn't find what I am looking for.

I want to make a remote control for an adressable RGB LED strip using a single knob. It will be controlled by an arduino.

I am looking for something that detects rotation as well as pressing down and pressing up/down left/right.

This will illustrate the possible movements I would like to have this. 
[image]

Comment: Do you require analog output from the stick, or will strictly digital suffice?

Comment: both ways are perfectly fine as long as I can process the output with an arduino.

Answer (score 1):

I used "six axis joystick with rotation" as the search terms and came up with an open-source resource from the [UNMND web site](http://www.unmnd.com/6-axis-joystick.html). It appeals to me because I like to build stuff and this one is very much a home-build type of project.

[image: 6-axis joystick image]

I have a 3dconnexion SpacePilot Pro which has the requirements you describe, but it is fairly expensive and may not necessarily link to an arduino or pi board.

My search found very little else suitable for your objective.

Comment: That is an amazing joystick! 
Yet this is not exactly what I am looking for.